# When resizing image it doesn't keep ratio?

Tags: php, html, css

When I upload a image on my websie it resizes to max 100 by max 100. The only problem is that is doesn't keep its ratio... for example : Original image is 200 by 400, after resize its 100 by 100 even though it should by 50 by 100.

SCRIPT :

```
<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imgprev')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .width(100)
                    .height(100);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

CALL :

```
            <div class="simplr-field ">
                <label class="left" for="small_image">
                    <strong>Huidige kleine afbeelding: </strong><br> (Hieronder vindt u de huidige kleine afbeelding.)
                    <br>
                    <img id="imgprev" src="<?=$post['small_image_url'];?>" alt="Afbeelding preview" style="width: 100px;">
            </div>
                <div class="simplr-field ">
                    <label class="left" for="small_image">
                        <strong>Wijzigen kleine afbeelding: </strong><br> (de gekozen afbeelding wordt automatisch geschaald naar een maximaal formaat van 100*100 pixels.
                        De bestaandsgrootte is 200kB maximaal. Alleen JPG, JPEG en PNG toegestaan.)
                    <br>
                        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="readURL(this)">
                </div>
```

Comment: Well yes, you have **.width(100).height(100)** in your jQuey. Remove one of them (width or height) and it should make it auto unless specified in CSS.

Comment: Instead of calling a function, why don't you use timhumb to resize your image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the width, and set the height to auto. That will preserve the aspect ratio.

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imgprev')
                    .attr('src', e.target.result)
                    .css({
                      width: '100px',
                      height: 'auto'
                    });
            };
```

Comment: but what if instead of 200 by 400 the image is 400 by 200. then width needs to go auto. I'm not changing every time :p

Comment: This answer will, and all the answers so far, will preserve the aspect ratio. So if you specify the width or the height, the other dimension is calculated according to the aspect ratio. If you need to change the aspect ratio, you have to specify the dimensions explicitly

Answer (score 1):

When you re-size an image, you have to give it a breathing space by making either the property value of the **height** or the **width** **Auto**

**HTML**

```
<div id="image-container">
<!-- Image Goes here -->
</div><!-- End Image Container -->
```

**CSS**

```
#image-container {
    width: 100px; /* Adjust as needed */
    height: 100px; /* Adjust as needed */
    overflow: hidden; /* Cuts off whatever goes beyond the given dimension */
}


 #image-container img {
        width: 100px;
        height: auto; /* Gives the image the breathing space as it adjusts */
    }
```